# Is there a way to update FB Ad URL Parameters using Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way to update ad URL Parameters with marketing api?

It is possible from FB Ads Manager, but we have more than 200 different ads and we want to automatically update their URL params from api instead of doing it manually.

I have checked FB marketing api refference, but couldn't find anything related.

Really need your help here.

UPDATE:

This is for those, who are searching for the same or similar thing.

The mechanics which ties Ad to Post or custom template is Ad Creative. You can find its API capabilities here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative

Unfortunately for Ad Creative you can only update Name, Ad Labels and Status. You can still create new Ad Creative with all desired fields and then assign it to Ad, but there is no way to update its `url_tags` field.

Comment: how did you duplicate Ad Creative and how did you replace new one with old Ad Creative?

Answer (score 0):

Right, the creative is basically immutable except for the fields you mentioned. Changing the URL tags could lead to exploits.
Is there a reason to want to edit an existing creative rather than create a duplicate with the URL tags modified?

Comment: Wont that remove all gathered comments and likes? I was afraid i would loose them cause they seem to be tied to creative.

Comment: @JanisPurins Did you ever get any further with this?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Yes, Not with the API, but you can add dynamic URL params now to include ad, adset, campaign names or ids

Comment: This should really be supported. Google Ads has this functionality with ValueTracks being modifiable via API. And an exploiter, who would be changing url parameters, is probably just as fine rebuilding the ad as described here. I don't see the supposed benefit in reality.